# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed.'

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am coding in ASP.NET (c# for code behind). The following code gives me a bug and I am not sure how to solve the problem

```
foreach (var sids in siddict)
{
    int sid = sids.Key;
    string gra = sids.Value;
    if (gra != string.Empty)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand("select classid,day,TIME_FORMAT(start,'%H:%i'),TIME_FORMAT(end,'%H:%i'),teacher from enroll where studentid=@sid", sqlconn);
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", sid);
        MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand("select classid,day,TIME_FORMAT(start,'%H:%i'),TIME_FORMAT(end,'%H:%i'),teacher from enroll where studentid=@sid", sqlconn);
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", sid);
        MySqlDataReader sdr2 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr2.Read())
        {
            string clid = sdr2.GetString(0);
            string couid = sdr2.GetString(0).Split('-')[0] + "-" +b sdr2.GetString(0).Split('-')[1];
            string day = sdr2.GetString(1).ToLower();
            string start = sdr2.GetString(2) + ":00";
            string end = sdr2.GetString(3) + ":00";
            string teacher = sdr2.GetString(4);
            sqlconn.Close();
            sqlconn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd4 = new MySqlCommand("select " + gra + " from classes where courseid=@cid and " + gra + " is null", sqlconn);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", couid);
            MySqlDataReader sdr3 = cmd4.ExecuteReader();
            if (sdr3.Read())
            {
                sqlconn.Close();
                sqlconn.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd5 = new MySqlCommand("delete from enroll where classid = @clid and studentid=@sid;update " + day + " set currentstudent=currentstudent-1 where classid=@clid and start=@start and end=@end and teacher=@teacher", sqlconn);
                cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clid", clid);
                cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", sid);
                cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", start);
                cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", end);
                cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacher", teacher);
                cmd5.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives an error of connection `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed.'` . I think it is because I closed it's original connection of reading sdr2 when opening a new connection for sdr3 and for cmd5. Any way to solve this?

Comment: Why do you have repeated Close, Open statements? Just open the connection when you start, and close it when done (or better yet, wrap your connection in a using statement which will close and dispose of it automatically when it falls out of scope)

Comment: @mason - Thanks for replying. The reason why I repeat close and open statements is because I have to close the connection and reopen it for the next command, otherwise it would give me a bug `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.'`

Comment: That's the wrong reaction to that error message. You should close the *reader* instead. The *"which"* in "which must be closed first" is referring to the reader, not the connection.

Comment: There are several red flags here. 1) You should never call `Close` on a connection, a command, or a reader. Always use the `using` statement. Then if you get that exception, it's a clear indication that you need a new connection to executate statements while you loop over a result set. 2) You're running statements in a loop. The specifics aren't clear (we don't see `cmd3.CommandText`) but you should be using set-based operations wherever possible. 3) String concatenation. Usually, this invokes "parameters", but in your case, it's more likely that "normalization" is what you need.

Comment: You can also use `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` in your connection string
please check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets

Comment: @MohtishamZubair: `MultipleActiveResultSets` is a SQL Server feature. OP is using MySQL.

Comment: @madreflection thanks for telling me about that. I am new to asp.net so I do not know the 'which' refers to sdr not the connection. I have changed the `sqlconn.Close()` and `sqlconn.Open()` statement to `sdr2.Close()`.

Comment: @Ken: To reiterate, you should *not* be calling `Close` on *any* of those objects. Wrap them in `using` statements and let the language *dispose* them (which will call `Close` as needed, but that's a detail with which you need not concern yourself).

Comment: @madreflection I assume you mean `using (MySqlDataReader sdr3 = cmd4.ExecuteReader())` right? I did that, however problem still exists. Any solution to this? Thanks

Comment: @MohtishamZubair Hi. Seems like MAR is not supported for mysql. And I don't quite get what you mean by 'OP is using MySQL'. Do you mind to explain more to me? Thanks

Comment: @Ken: "OP" = you, Original Poster. You are using MySQL.

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that. And that brings us to my later points: At the very least, you need a second connection so you can iterate over the first set on the first connection while you run other queries on the second connection.

Comment: Furthermore, running these queries in a loop is suboptimal at best. SQL can do some crazy-wonderful things using set-based operations. Procedural database access is significantly slower and, when queries are mixed with ADO.NET code, much more difficult to reason about. Please show the code that assigns `cmd3.CommandText`. Whatever *that* is, you can probably combine everything into one statement.

Comment: @Ken: Please [edit] your question when providing new details. Someone reading the question for the first time should have all relevant info without having to read the comments. While you're at it, include the whole method. There's this `gra` variable that's rather important and its definition is missing.

Comment: @madreflection Thanks for telling me about that. Updated :)

Comment: @Ken: SO questions have history so don't worry about informing readers about updates. Just edit it all together so it reads the same way you see it. I've done that for you, but I had to infer some closing braces in the process.

Comment: @madreflection thanks for editting it :)

Comment: @Ken: Now, if you can open a second connection, you just might be able to get this to work, but that's the low bar. Your database design is limiting you. You need to normalize your data.

Comment: SQL, the language, works with sets, not loops. You can write a SQL script that uses JOINS to update and delete multiple records at once, as needed. There's no reason to use a loop for this and certainly no reason to loop on the client side. You can write eg `DELETE t1 from t1 inner join t2 on ...`. The `FROM` and `WHERE` parts should return the records you want to delete, the same way you'd do in a `SELECT ... from t1 inner join t2`

Comment: @madreflection just tried, and it works. Thanks a LOT for your help. 
Yes I will have a look on normalizing the data, though not being familiar with dealing with databases. :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hi. Yes I know my method is not ideal at all. I originally tried to do all in one go but unfortunately my brain can't deal with the complexity of it. Also, I will have to learn more on SQL. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Ken: Take note of what Panagiotis Kanavos has said, but that's not going to be possible when you have multiple columns (identified by the `gra` variable) that represent the same kind of data. Once that's a single column with different values, you can use joins and perform those set-based operations. Learn normalization ASAP.